# What is wrong with the syntax of this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    print " ".join(line.strip() for line in f)
```

[Though the code seems to be correct, but facing syntax error !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aebFH.png)

Comment: If this is Py3, you must use `print` as a function: `print()`

Comment: Try `mystr = " "` then `mystr.join(...)`

Comment: Code works fine in python2.x, in Python3.x use print() as @TemporalWolf stated. So `print(" ".join(line.strip() for line in f))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3, print is a function. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Try:

```
with open('list.txt') as f:
    print(" ".join(line.strip() for line in f))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using python version 3 , Use this

```
   with open('line.txt') as f:
   print(" ".join(line.strip() for line in f))
```